# Taxonomy Term Block View Show Nodes For All Terms in Node?

Tags: 6, views

Hello i achived this once but for some reason i am having a problem with it this time.

Using D6 and Views 3. I have a block view for random videos.

- Taxonomy Term ID from URL
- Load default argument from node page,
- Validator: taxonomy term
- Argument Type - Term id's by , or +

Iv checked and unchecked both-

Allow multiple terms per argument

and

Allow multiple arguments to work together

without much success. The desired output would be on a node tagged with 'science' and 'spirituality' the block view would show nodes that are either tagged 'science' or 'spirituality'. At the moment i seem to be getting no results or only nodes tagged with both 'science + spirituality'.

Does anyone know the correct settings for me to show nodes with any of the node's tags?

Thanks

Comment: When u create your node you can chose multiple values(taxonomy terms) from one field, or you have two or more fields for taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for d6, but in d7 you can do it like this(i believe it can be done same way in d6)

In Contextual filters(your Arguments) you need to add `Nid` like you did, after add new argument `has taxonomy term ID` and in `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE` -> provide default value chose not `content from URL` but `PHP code` and do this:

You need to load node and get your taxonomy terms from field.

```
 $node = node_load(arg(1));
  if($node) {
  $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_YOURFIELDNAME');
  if($field) {
      foreach($node->field_YOURFIELDNAME[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $term) { $terms[] =  $term['tid'];          }
    return implode('+',$terms);
  } 
}
  else { return; }
```

it will return tids of selected taxonomy terms. But its a d7 way with Views 3.

Comment: mmm thanks neok i dont think its the same really for D6 Views 3. Previously i didnt have to add any code. It all seemed to work with a couple of counter intuitive settings but thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hello i am still struggling on with this. I have made up a simple view which you can see here http://pastebin.com/1khJEUCN

Comment: When viewing this node on my site the expected behaviour is for the right hand block to show node in 'chinese' and 'comedy records' (tags) http://onlinebanter.com/chinese/videos/monty-python-i-chinese at the moment it only shows 'chinese'

Comment: Ive went with neok's suggestion as maybe i never ever had it working like i hoped im thinking. I might be getting somewhere as i now get a white screen when viewing a node where the block is placed. It might ust be a problem with the php code for D6 http://pastebin.com/NpdCzuuq

Comment: sorry that was an updated view i last posted there with all the instructions followed as best i could. thanks

Comment: i think there might not be `field_get_items` for d6, read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840720/reading-node-field-values-in-module-code-using-drupal-6